# XCode 4.4 .strings file add new localization option gone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, localization

Upgraded to Xcode 4.4 today, and when clicking on my strings file and looking in the Utilities window, I no longer see a plus button allowing me to add a new language.

Where has this gone?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The +/- was removed starting in Xcode 4.4.  The way to add localizations is to go to your project settings pane (The same place where you would change the build settings of your project) and click on your project name under the *Project* heading.  You can then add localizations in the Localizations section.

[image: Localization Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! Gotta love how they keep moving these things!

Comment: And, XCode crashes every time I add a new one...yay.

Comment: Crashes just from there?  :-S  It didn't for me... but check out the developer forums they are talking about it over there too (Xcode 4.5, but same deal)

Comment: Yeah, I add a new language, it gives me the dialog asking what I want to localize, hit ok, then crash, every time. Will check the forums...

Comment: @NicHubbard - I'm getting the same issue with XCode 4.4.1 just crashing whenever attempting to add a new localization. Did you make any progress with this? Thanks.

Comment: I had the localized strings file added incorrectly. I just rebuilt from scratch.