# "+" to add localized string is not available in XCode 4.5.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, localization, interface-builder

I am working on a project which is using localizing support, few days back i had updated my xcode 4.3.2 to 4.5.1 which is the latest one and now client has just added new language thatz why when i went towards adding new file by following these steps

1. select the Localizable.strings file, you can see the "Localization" pane.
2. I can see my other languages file there

But no "+" or "-" is there, dont know how to add new language or its not longer supported or apple forget to add button here ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: It changed by Xcode 4.4 - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662775/xcode-4-4-strings-file-add-new-localization-option-gone