# How can I make an NSLocalizedString from something that is being #define?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, nslocalizedstring

How can I make an `NSLocalizedString` from something that is being `#define`?

What I have right now:

```
#define StationsControllerIdentifier @"Stations"
```

How I want it to be (but doesn't work):

```
#define StationsControllerIdentifier NSLocalizedString(@"Stations", @"stations menu btn")
```

Comment: use the pre-processor assistant in xcode to see how it is getting expanded.

Answer (score 0):

There's anything wrong with that. Did you added the necessary `Localizable.strings` files into your project and put on then the strings you wanna localize?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a file with .strings extension and specify below in there :

```
#define StationsControllerIdentifier @"Stations"
```

and then use it like

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Stations")
```

[XCode 4.4 .strings file add new localization option gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662775/xcode-4-4-strings-file-add-new-localization-option-gone)